# Multiple figures in tabular format

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption, wrapfigure

I know this issue has been discussed in a lot of other topics, but I couldn't make them work, and my issue is kind of special because it requires text and multiple images in each column, and I want to reference it as a figure.

What I want to obtain looks like this:
[image]

I have tried a lot of options with `subfig` and `subcaption` packages but none of them worked as expected, so I'm not putting the source code for them here.

My only requirement is that my figure needs to be wrapped inside this code:

```
\begin{figure*}
    % ...
    \caption{Caption for the whole figure}
    \label{fig:fig1} % I can do without the label too
\end{figure*}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just want a table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
   \centering
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
Input image&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}\\
Aligned face&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}\\
Apparent age&
1&2&3&4&5\\
Predicted age&
5&4&3&2&1
\end{tabular}

    \caption{Caption for the whole figure}
    \label{fig:fig1} % I can do without the label too
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you and other answerers so much. This seems to be working for me so I didn't try the other ones. +1 to all though :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with a `tabularx` environment, with the overall width set to `\textwidth`. This approach assures that the tabular material will fit inside the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,graphicx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page margins
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}c*{7}{C}@{}}
Input image &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic1} &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic2} &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic3} &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic4} &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic5} &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic6} &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic7} \\
Aligned face &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic8}  &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic9}  &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic10} &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic11} &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic12} &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic13} &
   \includegraphics[ width=\linewidth, height=\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{pic14} \\
Apparent age & 57 & 17 & 40 & 50 & 30 & 79 & 12 \\
Predicted age & 57.75 & 16.15 & 39.43 & 49.15 & 32.06 & 78.99 & 12.78 \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{...} \label{fig:...}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not a tabular?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\photo}[1]{%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rcc}
    Input image &   \photo{example-image-a} &  \photo{example-image-a} \\
    Aligned face &  \photo{example-image-b} &  \photo{example-image-b} \\
    Apparent &      10                      &  11 \\
    Predicted &     11                      & 12 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... crossed answers.

Comment: How would you label each one 1.1a, 1.1b like that?

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi it would be better to ask a new question for this... if you do I'll post an answer.  You can use my code above as a MWE for the question.