# How to insert subfigures in the form of 'T' shape?

Tags: subfloats

can someone please help me insert subfigures in the form of 'T' shape? Also how to control the spacing between the two subfigures for eg. the horizontal spacing between 'subfigure1' and 'subfigure2' and also the vertical spacing between 'subfigure3' and 'subfigure4' (I am referring to the subfigures in the attached image). Is it possible to insert a thin line according to the height of the subfigure, so as to separate the two subfigures which are next to each other. ?

[image: subfigures in the form of 'T' shape]

Comment: tabular environment--first row two figures--second row multicolumn(2) for one figure--third row same as second row

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301992/multiple-figures-in-tabular-format

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383254/placing-figures-inside-table-with-captions-for-each

Comment: http://www.jason-french.com/blog/2012/01/17/using-figures-within-tables-in-latex

Comment: What have you done so far and whats the problem? Im sure you will find helful content on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Some duck}
    \label{fig:duck1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Some other duck}
    \label{fig:duck2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Another duck}
    \label{fig:duck3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Another duck the second time}
    \label{fig:duck4}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Many ducks!}
  \label{fig:manyducks}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With vertical line and some custom spacing added

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
  \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Some duck}
    \label{fig:duck1}
  \end{subfigure} &
  \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Some other duck}
    \label{fig:duck2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \end{tabular}
  \vspace{1cm}\par
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Another duck}
    \label{fig:duck3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \vspace{2cm}\par
  \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.32\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Another duck the second time}
    \label{fig:duck4}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Many ducks!}
  \label{fig:manyducks}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Fractal for the first sample code i.e. no line between the subfigures 1 and 2, can you please tell how can I adjust the horizontal space between the subfigures 1 and 2. I tried using \hspace, the subfigure 1 is cropped. Whereas if I use \hfill, the subfigures are not inserted at in the centre of the page, also the subfigure 2 is pushed towards the right margin (rather it is even crossing the margin) and also the subcaptions are not appearing at the center of the subfigures. Can you please help me fix this?

Comment: @Giri Use the second code, substitute `c|c` with something like `c@{\hspace{1cm}}c`.

Comment: I tried but now the subfigures 1 and 2 are inserted one below the other. Also latex is printing "@" and "c"  to the left of subfigure 1.

Comment: Probably you are breaking something -- two cells of the same row can't be inserted one below another.

Comment: You are right. My bad I forgot to insert {}. I am new to latex. So can you please suggest a source for learning various ways of inserting figures in latex.

Comment: I am able to insert horizontal space. But the subcaptions are not printed at the centre of the subfigures, Also the subfigure 2 is pushed towards the right. Can you please help me fix this?

Comment: You need `\centering` to center the subcaptions. If it is still there, the caption must be at the center, unless your figure is too big (if it is the case, scale your figure down)